# Адаптивная верстка на jsp странице

Tags: java, html, css, bootstrap, jsp

Есть сверстанная на Bootstrap 3 страница, которую копипастом вставляю на jsp. Есть файл css, в котором определяется, как будут вести себя колонки при различной ширине экрана. Делается это через @media screen:

[image: @media screen]

При запуске приложения все стили работают нормально, кроме вот этой адаптивной верстки:

[image: Сайт на jsp]

То есть, то, что должно стать псевдо-элементом, и определить количество и ширину колонок, добавляется строчкой текста вначале, а колонки растягиваются по ширине страницы. Код jsp, с колонками, куда должен добавляться псевдо-элемент:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row masonry" data-columns>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">Заголовок</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="caption">                        
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    </div>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">Подробнее</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star">5</span>
                    <span class="pull-right my-grey-text">Дедова Маргарита : 31:12:2017</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
```

Дело в jsp или css?

Comment: А не легче вписать в класс col-md-3? Дело в CSS, он не применяет их. Он просто прописал тот текст который вы задали ему в контенте)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в CSS.

```
selector::before {
  content: "someContent";
}
```

прописывает `someContent` в содержимое, перед тегом.

`col-xs-4` это класс `bootstrap`-а, и если вы его хотите применить, то надо указывать его в классе

```
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
```

И при этом не нужно писать Media Query так как `col-xs-4` уже сам зависит от расширения экрана по своему определению в `bootstrap`. Он означает что будет использовано 4 колонки из 12 при очень маленьких размерах экрана.

Comment: А если мне нужно предусмотреть сразу несколько вариантов? Когда должны быть 5,4,3,2 колонки из 12? Я так понимаю, Media Query как раз это и делает, то есть, понимает, когда какой экран, и оборачивает содержимое в нужный div с количеством колонок. Можно ли как-то обойти создание этих псевдо div-ов и сохранить адаптивность?

Comment: @СофьяКарева отличный вопрос, если вы используете нативный HTML, то да, это делается на MediaQuery, но если вы используете Bootstrap то в этом нету необходимости и можно сделать проще. Просто у одного div-а делается несколько классов, например `class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3"` это означает что на малых экранах будет в одну колонку, на средних в две, и на больших в четыре. В этом как раз сила bootstrap что можно такую адаптивности и медийность делать просто задавая нужные классы.

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо, это работает!

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, основная проблема была в salvattore.js, который должен обрабатывать css правила на jsp странице. То есть, добавления js в jsp. Если просто скопировать код из salvattore.js на страницу, псевдо-элементы создаются и вся адаптивная красота работает. Но если с его прикреплением остаются проблемы, помогает ответ выше про присвоение нескольких классов "col-xs-12 ...".